# AB+B((B+C')+B'C) can be simplified to

Tags: boolean-algebra

The answer is B+C but When I tried to solve I got a different answer, which is B.

### The way I solved

AB+B((B+C')+B'C) 
=AB+B(B+C')+BB'C  
=AB+BB+BC'+BB'C 
=(BB'C=0,BB=B) then 
AB+B+BC' 
Taking B out frm all terms 
B(A+1+C')
=B 
[A+1+C'=1]

What is the problem in my solution

Comment: What does $C'$ mean?

Comment: Complement of C.

Comment: What does $A+B$ mean then? $A \cup B?$ What about $AB$?

Comment: A+B means A or B  A.B means A and B

Comment: @ganeshie8 actually this is not a text book qn. It was aksed in a competitive examination and B+C was there in the final answerkey :(. Thanks for you response

Comment: @Abhijith ohk :) there's nothing wrong in your work. My guess is some mistake from the answer key or some typo in the given expression itself.. please see my answer...

Comment: I don't know what theorems you have available, but $(B+C')+B'C=True$, so then you have $AB+B=B$

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks all good. That means textbook answer $B+C$ must be incorrect, or there is a typo in the given expression.

Let's check this by plugging in $B=0$ and $C=1$:
$B+C = 0+1 = 1$
$AB+B((B+C')+B'C)  = A0 + 0(...) = 0+0 = 0$

Thus $B+C$ cannot be the simplified form. However, you would get the textbook answer if the given expression had been:
$$AB+B(B+C')+B'C $$

Comment: Any Boolean Algebra can be represented as a family of subsets of a set $X$, with $AB=A\cap B$ and $A+B=A\cup B$, with $1=X$ and $0=\emptyset$. If we apply this to  the formula of  the Q it reduces to $B$..........+1